# A simple decorator written as a class, which counts how many times a function has been called

Tags: python, python-3.x, meta-programming

Can I improve its typing? Is there any other improvement or pythonic change that you would do?

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# This is mostly so that I practice using a class as a decorator.
class CountCalls:
    """Logs to DEBUG how many times a function gets called, saves the result in a newly created attribute `num_calls`."""
    def __init__(self, func: F) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func
        self.num_calls: int = 0
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.func.__name__)
        self.last_return_value = None

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self.num_calls += 1
        self._logger.debug(' called %s times', self.num_calls)
        self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.last_return_value
```

Here's the decorator in action:

```py
>>> @CountCalls
... def asdf(var: str):
...     print(var)
...     return len(var)
... 
>>> asdf('Laur')
Laur
4
DEBUG:__main__.asdf: called 1 times
>>> asdf('python 3')
DEBUG:__main__.asdf: called 2 times
python 3
8
>>> asdf(3)
DEBUG:__main__.asdf: called 3 times
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Projects/Python/he/src/he/decorators.py", line 156, in __call__
    self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<input>", line 4, in asdf
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
>>> asdf.num_calls
3
```

Comment: FWIW, the [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module may be of use for this sort of thing. Note that [the `Mock` classes are currently not typed due to issues with `mypy`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/feeb4e71ef16932153a06fc26ce7a02ffdbaa2ab). You can see the previous, typed code in the link and I take a full look once I get to a computer.

Comment: I updated the "decorator in action" part to make it more readable.  I don't know what you're saying there about mock typing though.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try to improve the typing would be to type the method itself (although I'm not sure how well tools support it). Also, leading/trailing whitespace should be up to the logger, not the code using it.

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# This is mostly so that I practice using a class as a decorator.
class CountCalls:
    """Logs to DEBUG how many times a function gets called, saves the result in a newly created attribute `num_calls`."""
    def __init__(self, func: F) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func
        self.num_calls: int = 0
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.func.__name__)
        self.last_return_value = None

    __call__: F

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self.num_calls += 1
        self._logger.debug(f'called %s times', self.num_calls)
        self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.last_return_value
```

As for the code itself, you could make a callback-based API.

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# This is mostly so that I practice using a class as a decorator.
class CountCalls:
    """Logs to DEBUG how many times a function gets called, saves the result in a newly created attribute `num_calls`."""
    def __init__(self, func: F, callback: Optional[Callable[[int, Tuple[Any], Dict[str, Any]], Any]] = None) -> None:
        if callback is None:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.func.__name__)

            def callback(num_calls: int, args: Tuple[Any], kwargs: Dict[str, Any]):
                self._logger.debug(f'called %s times', self.num_calls)

        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func        
        self.callback = callback
        self.num_calls: int = 0
        self.last_return_value = None

    __call__: F

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self.num_calls += 1
        self.callback(self.num_calls, args, kwargs)
        self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.last_return_value
```

Or with the number of calls tracked in the callback (for increased flexibility):

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# This is mostly so that I practice using a class as a decorator.
class CountCalls:
    """Logs to DEBUG how many times a function gets called, saves the result in a newly created attribute `num_calls`."""
    def __init__(self, func: F, callback: Optional[Callable[[int, Tuple[Any], Dict[str, Any]], Any]] = None) -> None:
        if callback is None:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.func.__name__)
            num_calls: int = 0

            def callback(args: Tuple[Any], kwargs: Dict[str, Any]):
                nonlocal num_calls  # Not sure if this is necessary or not
                num_calls += 1
                self._logger.debug(f'called %s times', self.num_calls)

        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func        
        self.callback = callback
        self.last_return_value = None

    __call__: F

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self.callback(self.num_calls, args, kwargs)
        self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.last_return_value
```

Earlier, to pass a keyword argument while using it, `@functools.partial(CountCalls, callback=callback)` was needed. Now, `@CountCalls(callback=callback)` can be used instead.

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# This is mostly so that I practice using a class as a decorator.
class CountCalls:
    """Logs to DEBUG how many times a function gets called, saves the result in a newly created attribute `num_calls`."""
    def __init__(self, func: F = None, callback: Optional[Callable[[int, Tuple[Any], Dict[str, Any]], Any]] = None) -> None:
        if callback is None:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.func.__name__)
            num_calls: int = 0

            def callback(args: Tuple[Any], kwargs: Dict[str, Any]):
                nonlocal num_calls  # Not sure if this is necessary or not
                num_calls += 1
                self._logger.debug(f'called %s times', self.num_calls)

        if func is None:
            return functools.partial(CountCalls, callback=callback)

        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func        
        self.callback = callback
        self.last_return_value = None

    __call__: F

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self.callback(self.num_calls, args, kwargs)
        self.last_return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.last_return_value
```

(Note: none of this code has been tested.)

Comment: [Using `%`-formatting is the default way for the `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-particular-formatting-styles-throughout-your-application) (and it is not going to change due to backward compatibility). It is a bit special in that regard. One can change it to use parts of the `str.format` syntax, but not with keyword arguments. Using `f-string`s here is actually a potentially bad idea, because normally the string formatting is only performed if the message is of the right logging level, which means a lot when not having to do it for debug messages.

Comment: Typing the `__call__` method itself is genius. Regarding f-strings in logging, I have to agree with @Graipher that string interpolation is better suited for the logging module - that's why I used it in the first place.

I'm starting to understand now what's with the callback part that you proposed, and that's genius as well; if I understand correctly, it allows changing the functionality of the decorator by supplying an optional function... I'll go into test mode for that part.

Comment: @LaurențiuAndronache It would be nice if Python supported additional types of `TypeVar`s for when tricks like this don't work (such as with typing the callback), but oh well... Also, with the callback API, I'll add a version where the number of calls is tracked by the callback for increased flexibility.

Comment: note that in both examples with callbacks, you can't actually supply a callback to the decorator. `TypeError: b() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: @LaurențiuAndronache Interesting.... What is `b`? The decorated function or the callback? What's its signature? Does the error occur when defining the decorated function or when calling it? How are you calling the decorator? I think `functools.partial` with a keyword argument (`callback`) is necessary.

Comment: I wanted to include more code, but it shows up badly as a comment... I was decorating like this:
```python
def b():
    pass
```

and then: 

```
@CountCalls(b)
def c():
    pass
```

which I understand why it doesn't work `__init__` would have to optionally return a decorator when it is called with args, in order to be usable with args...

Comment: What you currently have to do is to use `functools.partial(CountCalls, callback=b)` as a decorator. I'll edit the code to make it so that if only a callback is specified (via a keyword argument), it will return the `partial`.